# Pytest delete state between tests

Tags: pytest

I'm running multiple tests in pytest.
The problem is that each of those update state on an imported module.

On each test, I am importing like this:

```
from src.classification.main import main
```

I would like to reset the state of the modules on each of the tests of pytest, to start from a clean state.

Can you recommend a way to do so ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Use a function scoped fixture and import the package there. 
```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def import_package():
      from src.classification.main import main
      return main

def test_a(import_package):
       import_package()
```

Comment: I think I am having the same issue as OP. Tried this solution from @SilentGuy but getting this error: "Failed: Fixture "import_package" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly"

Comment: Yours is a different issue. You are importing a fixture directly. OP was importing a non-pytest module. 

You should look up how to use fixtures in a pytest test. That should help.